# Using if else in spark map reduce

Tags: apache-spark

I am a beginner in spark 
could you please help , how create check on first character on map before create map `RDD` ( if word.charAt(0) exist ) , and what if the condition go to else , this record not pass to `groupByKey`

```scala
val mapReduce = splitFile.map(word => (word.charAt(0), word.length)).groupByKey()
```

Comment: do all your transformation on RDD only, use filter function fo check if char0 exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter`: the resulting RDD will only contain the records that satisfy the predicate (a `T => Boolean` function for an `RDD[T]`), in this case - non-empty strings:

```
splitFile
  .filter(!_.isEmpty)
  .map(word => (word.charAt(0), word.length))
  .groupByKey()
```